# Rails bootstrap modal client side validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a bootstrap modal with ajax:

```
 <%= link_to 'Question', new_question_path, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-info' %>
```

_form_modal.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade" id="form_modal" tabindex='-1'>
  <%= simple_form_for @question, remote: true, validate: true do |f| %>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Question</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-inputs">
            <%= f.input :content, label: false %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= f.button :submit, "Ask", class:" btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

new.js.erb

```
 $('#remotecontainer').html('<%= j render "questions/form_modal", locals: { product: @product } %>');
 $('#form_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
 $('form[data-validate]').enableClientSideValidations();
 }).modal();
```

I'm accessing the modal through this: `<div id='remotecontainer'></div>`

The controller method:

```
def new
  @question = Question.new
end


def create
  @question = Question.new(question_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @question.save
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Question was successfully sent!" }
    else
      format.js { render 'new.js.erb'}
    end
  end
end
```

I have a validation inside the model: `validates_length_of :content, maximum: 70`

And I'm using the following two gems for the validations errors:

```
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'
```

The modal appears and if I submit the form with less then 70 characters the questions is created. But on the other hand if I type more then 70 characters, the validation error appears and something weird happens... If I type and re-submit the form with less then 70 characters it continues to give me the validation error and doesn't allow me to submit the form. I might be missing something here... So any ideas on how to fix this?

**Update**

Ok I tried this.... I added the exclamation mark to the controller create method: `if @question.save!` And I get the validation error at the console. The validation error doesnt appear on the modal at all. And then when I try to submit the form with lesser characters then 70, it goes through. So from my understanding something wrong with the two gems setup. Can anybody please give some help with this one?

```
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:14
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Content is too long (maximum is 70 characters)):
```

Comment: Is the validation performed by javascript?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Rodrigo, the validation works through the two gem I mentioned above, and yes I believe the gems are using javascript.

Comment: You can check this opening the Network tab of Dev Tools and look for an AJAX request.

Comment: Or just check your rails server logs to see if any request was made

Comment: `curl 'https://localhost:3000/assets/rails.validations.self-7ede4f32d93d43f53836b343c720442683029575668acd0fe95f2905b4fdb43f.js?body=1' \
-XGET`

Comment: `curl 'https://localhost:3000/assets/rails.validations.simple_form.bootstrap4.self-ef90d1aba71d65d8bab5853cef2a546b483e6cf8c1f5e4c0de816997431bd964.js?body=1' \
-XGET`

Comment: `curl 'https://localhost:3000/assets/rails.validations.simple_form.self-e0665902c5ca331262675bcccc5de4a3a39f83cc5c2d827a346284bda4e6ac47.js?body=1' \
-XGET`

Comment: @Rodrigo I go theese three from the browser network

Comment: @Rodrigo I added an update to my question with more info on what I think is happening. Please check it out if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I needed up putting this inside my modal:

```
<div id="formModal">
    <%= render partial: 'layouts/messages' %>
 </div>
```

This in as my controller method:

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(question_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @question.save
      flash.now[:success] = "Question was successfully sent!"
      format.js { render 'create.js.erb' }
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Something went wrong!"
      format.js { render 'create.js.erb' }
    end
  end
end
```

and this inside create.js.erb

```
$("#formModal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'layouts/messages') %>");
```